# Elegant way to select key in object of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

Consider having the following json

```
[
{'key1': { ... }},
{'key2': { ... }},
{'key3': { ... }}
]
```

I want to extract the keys for those objects in an elegant way, the following code is working, but it seems ugly to me.

```
let result = objects.map(o => Object.keys(o))[0]
```

the `[0]` at the end because the returned value is an array of array

Comment: Your JSON seems invalid.

Comment: I miss typed the JSON, it should be [
{'key1': { ... }},
{'key2': { ... }},
{'key3': { ... }}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.concat()` and `.map()` methods to get the desired result:

```js
let data = [
  {'key1': { }},
  {'key2': { }},
  {'key3': { }}
];

let result = [].concat(...data.map(Object.keys));

console.log(result);
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

An array can only hold values, objects hold key/value pairs. Don't forget to use `JSON.parse(json)` before actually manipulating the data.

I'm guessing you need something along the lines of:

```
const list = [
    {1: "one"},
    {2: "two"}, 
    {3: "three"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your JSON.

```
const data = [
  { 'key2': {  }} ,
  {'key1': {  }},
  {'key3': {  }}
];

const result = [].concat.apply([], data.map(Object.keys));
console.log(result);
```